# Should I document Exceptions even though they are already documented in their Interface?

Tags: c#, resharper, documentation

ReSharper is throwing a warning at me, saying that my exception is not documented. When I use the quick documentation tool of ReSharper (default keybinding <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) it clearly shows the exception of the inherited documentation.

So I'm wondering. Is this an issue with ReSharper or should I actually declare the exception again?

[image]

---

My code broken down to the important parts

```
public interface IMyService 
{
    /// <summary>...</summary>
    /// <exception cref="CantMoveForwardException">
    ///     If <see cref="CanMoveForward"/> returns <see langword="false" />.
    /// </exception>
    void MoveForward();
}

public class MyService : IMyService 
{
    public void MoveForward()
    {
    }
}

public sealed class CantMoveForwardException : Exception
{
    public CantMoveForwardException(string message) : base(message) 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: CantMoveForwardException class may not have documentation. Your other comments are fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should add comments to CantMoveForwardException class. Here is the simple option:

```
/// <inheritdoc/>
public sealed class CantMoveForwardException : Exception
{
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public CantMoveForwardException(string message) : base(message) 
    {
    }
}
```